# Use a PowerShell hash's key/values with Pester TestCases

Tags: powershell, pester, powershell-7.0, pester-5

I would like to pass the key/values of a PowerShell hash to a Pester unit test, via the `TestCases` parameter:

```
BeforeAll {
  $Expected = @{
    Address1='Address1'
    Address2='Address2'
    City='City'
    RegionCode='RegionCode'
    PostalCode='PostalCode'
  }
}

BeforeEach {
  Mock Invoke-SqlCmd
  Invoke-MyFunction @Expected
}

It "sets the column '<Name>' with the value '<Value>'" -TestCases ( $Optional.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { @{Name=$_.Key; Value=$_.Value} } ) {
    param($Name, $Value)
    
    $Test = "*{0}='{1}'*" -f $Name, $Value

    Assert-MockCalled Invoke-Sqlcmd -ParameterFilter {
        $Query -like $Test
    }

}
```

But can't seem to get the hash's properties 'shaped' correctly to get the tests to work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that you need to build the test cases needs to be in a `BeforeDiscovery { ... }` block.  The code in `BeforeAll { ... }` gets deferred until execution of the tests, however your `$expected` hashtable needs to be available earlier than that *before* discovery in order to build each of the tests from your test cases.  In addition to that you need to nest your `It { ... }` blocks in either a `Describe` or `Context` block

Update: per your comment - In order to make `$Expected` available to the test scopes without duplicating the assignment in the BeforeEach block you can set the variable's scope to script scope

```
BeforeDiscovery {
    $script:Expected = @{
        Address1   = 'Value_Address1'
        Address2   = 'Value_Address2'
        City       = 'Value_City'
        RegionCode = 'Value_RegionCode'
        PostalCode = 'Value_PostalCode'
    }
}

Describe "Need a describe or context block" {
    BeforeEach {
        Mock Invoke-SqlCmd
        Invoke-MyFunction @Expected
    }

    It "sets the column '<Name>' with the value '<Value>'" -TestCases (
         $Expected.GetEnumerator() | 
            ForEach-Object { @{Name = $_.Key; Value = $_.Value } } 
    ) {
        #   param($Name, $Value)

        $Test = "*{0}='{1}'*" -f $Name, $Value

        #   Assert-MockCalled Invoke-Sqlcmd -ParameterFilter {
        #       $Query -like $Test
        #   }

    }
}
```

Output

```
Pester v5.3.1

Starting discovery in 1 files.
Discovery found 5 tests in 25ms.
Running tests.

Running tests from 'C:\temp\powershell\pester.tests.ps1'
Describing Need a describe or context block
  [+] sets the column 'RegionCode' with the value 'Value_RegionCode' 8ms (4ms|4ms)
  [+] sets the column 'City' with the value 'Value_City' 2ms (1ms|1ms)
  [+] sets the column 'Address2' with the value 'Value_Address2' 5ms (1ms|3ms)
  [+] sets the column 'PostalCode' with the value 'Value_PostalCode' 3ms (1ms|2ms)
  [+] sets the column 'Address1' with the value 'Value_Address1' 3ms (1ms|2ms)
Tests completed in 168ms
Tests Passed: 5, Failed: 0, Skipped: 0 NotRun: 0
```

See Pester's v5 [Discovery and Run](https://pester-docs.netlify.app/docs/usage/discovery-and-run) docs

Paraphrased from that page:
This is what happens during the initial Discovery phase when you run Invoke-Pester

- Test script file is invoked
- `BeforeAll` function runs ONLY saving the scriptblock provided to it, not executing it (yet) **Hashtable and other variables inside this block have not been created yet**
- `Describe` function runs AND invokes the scriptblock provided to it in order to collect information about the tests contained inside it. Note: `Describe` and `Context` scriptblocks are the only scriptblocks that are run during discovery
- All parameters (including `-TestCases`) that are provided to the `It` function are ***evaluated by PowerShell*** (this is where the hashtable is needed however sadly it hasn't been brought into existence yet)
- `It` function runs saving (NOT running) the code contained generating the tests, 1 per each item in the previously evaluated `-TestCases` array
- `Write-Host "Discovery done."` is run.

Comment: Moving the `$Expected` hash fixed the `TestCases` issue, but created a new one: `$Expected` is not available in the `Context`'s `BeforeEach`.  I created a copy of the hash in `BeforeAll` which fixed the problem, albeit with some code repetition.

Comment: Ah right.  For that you can define $Expected with script scope which would make it available in BeforeEach and the other scopes.  `$script:Expected = @{ ... }`